# Placeholder attribute on text input with iOS 6 from landscape to portrait

Tags: html, ios6, landscape, viewport, placeholder

I have a problem after updating to iOS 6 that is driving me nuts.

It looks like any time I have the attribute "placeholder" on an input field, while rotating from
Portrait to Landscape and back to Portrait again the page shifts some pixels on the left side causing a horizontal bar.

I concluded after long research that it has to be something related to the meta viewport because every time I use the content="width=device-width" all works fine.

P.S Yes I really need to have a percent width on the input so as to have liquid design:)

Here is the example to recreate the issue. Thanks...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:100%;background-color:red">
        <input id="testInput"  placeholder="test" style="width:90%;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It pains me that it took almost 3 days to find that the placeholder was the issue causing this pixel shift.  Is this bug documented anywhere on apples site?

Comment: Hello Abadaba, as far as I know it is NOT documented. I just reported here to save some people's time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this problem.
and fix it.

(URL : http://mooki83.tistory.com/2656550 (in korean))

testURL : http://mooki83.da.to/m/testios6.html

javascript :

```
/* Optimized PLACEHOLDER for iOS6 - Mooki ( http://mooki83.tistory.com ) */


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("orientationchange.fm_optimizeInput", fm_optimizeInput);
});

function fm_optimizeInput(){
    $("input[placeholder],textarea[placeholder]").each(function(){
        var tmpText = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        if ( tmpText != "" ) {
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "").attr("placeholder", tmpText);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: would love to see a non-js fix

Comment: That is a valid answer. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Applying "overflow: hidden;" on the containing element solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

CSS fix:

```
body>div {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non js answer

Add `overflow:hidden` to parent element 
and it will work like a charm