# iOS6 landscape to portrait breaks the layout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, responsive-design

I'm working on a web app that's responsive. I have set the `viewport` meta tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

*I have no problems with orientation anywhere but on `iOS6`*. On that particular `iOS`, when I change the orientation from landscape to portrait the content keeps the correct aspect ratio but partly disappears to the left, leaving a blank space to the right.

When I open the debugger for the `iOS Simulator` (*Safari > Develop > iPhone Simulator > URL*) and click at the `html` tag - which is not overflowed - the page snaps back to where it should have been.

Note that I'm relying on the `viewport` meta tag to get this done and not using any `iOS` proprietary orientation mode. It works fine on:

- `iOS5.1.0` *tested on iOS Simulator*
- `iOS7.0.0` *tested on a real iPhone*

We don't support `iOS4` nor lower versions. Anyone experiencing the same?

Comment: This question might smell like "too localized", but it might as well be a poorly documented iOS6 bug... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was an input field that caused the page to break when changing orientation from landscape to portrait.

After even more digging, I found that the `placeholder` text was the problem's root cause. Taking the placeholder away would solve the problem. But since it was a problem exclusive to `iOS6`, I had to find another solution... [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582788/placeholder-attribute-on-text-input-with-ios-6-from-landscape-to-portrait/13656260) let me to the right direction.

All I had to do was to give the input field's parent element (in this case a form) `overflow: hidden`.